# Function with 2 different generic objects

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I´m trying to do the following:

I have a class with a virtual method like this:

```
public virtual Event<T> Execute<T>(T message)
```

And that´s what I want:

Event T can be different of T message. For example: sometimes I need a function like this:

```
public override Event<Bitmap> Execute(string message)
```

But of course, I get the following error "no suitable method found to override".

Is there any way to do this? Use 2 types of generic objects using this override?

**Note:** I can change the virtual method, but the other classes always have to inherit this one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to override it, override is used to change a method inherited from another class.
If i understood correctly you want to ***overload*** this method, omit ***override*** and type ***virtual*** instead.

```
public virtual Event<Bitmap> Execute(string message)
```

When you will call this function the compiler will choose most appropriate method in dependence of what number/types of values you have passed to the method.

Comment: Wow. Thank you Adrian, guess that´s what I want!!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should move the generic type to the class or an interface and then implement/extend the `Execute` method:

```
public interface IExecutor<T>
{
    Event<T> Execute();
}

public class BitmapExecutor : IExecutor<Bitmap>
{
    Event<Bitmap> Execute() { ... }
}
```

It doesn't make sense to have an `Execute<T>` method, since that implies that it is valid for any supplied type `T`, rather than specific ones.

Comment: That´s a good idea! Thank you Lee! I will check the most proper solution using your answer =))

Answer (score 1):

You could declare another overload for your method like this:

```
public virtual Event<K> Execute<T>(T message)
```

Comment: You can do that, but the syntax is wrong. You need to specific both types and those types will be unrelated, so you cannot work with them unless you do some runtime typecasting, removing advantage of generic.